# function Credential.changeset/2 is undefined (module Credential is not available)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I tried to follow [Writing Web-facing](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.0-rc.3/contexts.html) tutorial but when I added the email as credential I got this:

```
function Credential.changeset/2 is undefined (module Credential is not available)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you maybe forgot to add an `alias` in that module? You probably need to add `alias Hello.Accounts.Credential` to the module that's throwing this error so that Elixir knows `Credential` is actually `Hello.Accounts.Credential`.

Comment: It works thanks, I added the credential's alias at the top of the module...just after the user's alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial defines a module named `Hello.Accounts.Credential` and the line of code that throws an error for you uses the name `Credential` and says that the module is not available. You (or the tutorial) most likely forgot to add an `alias` call in the module that throws this error for you. Adding the following to that module should fix this:

```
alias Hello.Accounts.Credential
```

Comment: following the same tutorial, I got `[info]  alter table students`  `(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P01 (undefined_table): relation "staff" does not exist ` , Even if I put the `flush()` label in the migration's file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the

```
alias Hello.Accounts.Credential
```

To the `Hello.Accounts.User` module (lib/hello/accounts/user.ex).

That step is easy to miss when following the tutorial.